# Android Test - Chamar Método

Tags: android, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit, testes-funcionais

Gostaria de saber, se no android Unit test teria a possibilidade de chamar métodos isolados do código, ou se somente chamando activitys, botões...
pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei nada falando sobre

Comment: Gomes, parece que você procurou em lugares errados, por que na documentação oficial do Android, tem um tópico falando sobre isso, olhe [aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/testing.html), acredito que lhe ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem acesso total a todos os métodos da activity seja implicitamente ou explicitamente.

Tipo:

```
public void testNomeAplicacao() {
      TextView nomeAplicacao = (TextView) demo.findViewById(R.id.nomeAplicacao);
      assertEquals(nomeAplicacao.getText().toString(), "Helo World, EuAndroid");
```

}

Mais informações [aqui](http://douglasalipio.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/teste-junit-para-android/)